# Show tangent of evolute is normal to original curve

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, parametrization

The evolute of a curve R(t) is the locus of the centers of curvature of the curve. Using the parametric formulas, show that the tangent to the evolute is normal to the original curve.

I know that the evolute is e(t) = R(t) + N(t)/k(t). I then take the derivative to find the tangent and get e'(t) = R'(t) - (k'(t)N(t))/(k(t))^2 + N'(t)/k(t).

I know I need to take the dot product to show that this equation is perpendicular to the tangent of the original curve. However, I think I am missing something. Do I need to reparameterize the curves in terms of s?

Comment: You lose nothing by assuming that $R(s)$ starts off arclength parametrized. Then use the Frenet equations to simplify the expression you have derived. And you're done.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Okay so I know that N'(s)/k(s)=-T(s). And I think that the first term R'(s) is equivalent to T(s), at least in the sense that they are in the same direction. So that cancels them out. But what can I do to the middle term to simplify it? I tried substituting T'(s)/k(s) for N(s), but that only gave me (k'(s)T'(s))/(k(s))^3.

Comment: The middle term is all that's left, and it's in the direction of the principal normal. What angle does that make with the tangent $T(s)$? :)

Comment: It makes a right angle! Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to stop at each step and remember what you're trying to do! Enjoy differential geometry!