# Need help with exercise 7 from section 1.5 (Do Carmo's differential geometry book)

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

I'm reading the classical [Do Carmo's differential geometry book](http://www.math.uni.lodz.pl/~maczar/ggk/do%20Carmo,%20Differential%20Geometry%20of%20Curves%20and%20Surfaces.pdf) and I'm having trouble to prove the item b of the question 7 from section 1.5 (page 23):

[image]

**My attempt**

My attempt was to fix a normal line $l_1:\alpha(t_1)+\lambda n(t_1)$ and take a function $f(t)$ which gives me the intersection point of the normal line at $\alpha(t)$ and $l_1$ for each $t$. Afterwards, I took the limit $t\to t_1$.

This approach didn't give me anything, just a cumbersome $0/0$ limit.

Any hint? maybe a simpler approach?

Comment: You can find the first part here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933754/show-tangent-of-evolute-is-normal-to-original-curve

Comment: @ab123 Thank you, but I know how to solve the item a.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very rigorous proof but...

You proved in part a, that normal to $\alpha$ at $t$ is tangent at $t$ to evolute of $\alpha$ at $t$
So,  normal to $\alpha$ at $t_1$ is tangent at $t_1$ to evolute of $\alpha$ ,$\quad$ and  normal to $\alpha$ at $t_2$ is tangent at $t_2$ to evolute of $\alpha$, where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are very close points on the evolute.

So, as $t_1$ approaches $t_2$, tangents at very close points on a curve will converge to a point on the curve (the evolute here).